# Is it a bad idea to keep a fixed global_work_size and local_work_size when the number of elements to be processed grow randomly?

Tags: opencl

Often it is advised to keep the `global_work_size` the same as the logical amount of "elements" you must process. My application doesn't have such a thing, though. If I have `N` elements that need to be processed, then, after a single kernel pass, I will have `M` elements - a completely different number that doesn't depend on `N`.

In order to deal with this situation, I could write a loop such as:

```
while (elementsToBeProcessed)
    read "elementsToBeProcessed" variable from device
    enqueue ND range kernel with global_work_size = elemnetsToBeProcessed
```

But that requires one read per pass. An alternative would be to keep everything inside the GPU, by calling `enqueueNDRangeKernel` **only once, with a fixed global_work_size and local_work_size matching the GPU layout** and then use a master thread to synchronize the computation within.

My question is simple: is my intuition correct that the second option is better, or is there any reason to go with the first?

Answer (score 4):

That is a tricky problem, which way to take. And depends on the global size values you are going to have and how much they change over time.

**A read per pass:** (better for highly changing values)

- Fitted global size, all the work items will do useful work
- Unfitted local size for the HW, if the work size is small
- Blocking behavior in the queue, bad device utilization
- Easy to understand and debug

**Fixed kernel launch size:** (better for stable but changing values)

- Un-fitted global size, may waste some time running null work items
- Fitted local size to the device
- Non blocking behavior, 100% device usage
- Complex to debug

As some answers already say, OpenCL 2.0 is the solution, by using pipes. But it is also possible to use another OpenCL 2.0 feature, kernel calling inside kernels. So that your kernels can launch the next batch of kernels without CPU intervention.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good if you can avoid transferring data between host and device, even if it means little bit more work on the device. In many applications data transferring is the slowest part.

To find out better solution for your system configuration, you need to test both of them. If you are targeting to multiple platforms then the second one should be faster in general. But there are lot of things that can make it slower. For example the code for it might be harder to optimize for the compilers or the data access pattern might lead to more cache misses.

If you are targeting to OpenCL 2.0, [pipes](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/pipeFunctions.html) might be something you want to look at for this kind of random amount of elements.  (Before I get some down votes because of the platforms not supporting 2.0, AMD has promised 2.0 drivers to come this year) With pipes, you can make producer kernel and consumer kernel. Consumer kernel can start work as soon as it has enough items to work on. This might lead to better utilization of all resources.

Answer (score 1):

The tradeoff: The performance hit for doing the readback is that the GPU will be idle waiting for work, whereas if you just enqueue a bunch of kernels it will stay busy.

Simple: So I think the answer depends on how much elementsToBeProcessed will vary. If a sequence of runs might be (for example) 20000, 19760, 15789, 19345 then I'd always run 20000 and have a few idle work items. On the other hand, if a typical pattern is 20000, 4236, 1234, 9000 then I'd read back elementsToBeProcessed and enqueue the kernel for only what is needed.

Advanced: If your pattern is monotonically decreasing you could interleave the readback with the kernel enqueue, so that you're always keeping the GPU busy but you're also making them smaller as you go. Between every kernel enqueue start an async double-buffered readback of a copy of the elementsToBeProcessed and use it for the kernel *after* the one you enqueue next.

Like this:

1. elementsToBeProcessedA = starting value
2. elementsToBeProcessedB = starting value
3. eventA = NULL
4. eventB = NULL
5. Enqueue kernel with NDRange of elementsToBeProcessedA
6. non-blocking clEnqueueReadBuffer for elementsToBeProcessedA, taking eventA
7. if non-null, wait on eventB, release event
8. Enqueue kernel with NDRange of elementsToBeProcessedB
9. non-blocking clEnqueueReadBuffer for elementsToBeProcessedB, taking eventB
10. if non-null, wait on eventA, release event
11. goto 5

This will kepp the GPU fully saturated and yet will use smaller elementsToBeProcessed as it goes. It will *not* handle the case where elementsToBeProcessed *increases* so don't do it this way if that is the case.

Comment: Of course this is for OpenCL 1.x. If you have access to OpenCL 2.0 use pipes or dynamic parallelism.

Comment: I love you interleaved approach of "read and run last value read", for gradually decreasing values.

Comment: Thank you @DarkZeros; coming from you that's a real compliment!

Comment: I just noticed in the title is says the elements can *grow* randomly so this won't be useful.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution: Always run a fixed number of global work items, enough to fill the GPU but not more. Each work item should then look at the total number of items to be done for this pass (elementsToBeProcessed) and then do it's portion of the total.

```
uint elementsToBeProcessed = <read from global memory>
uint step = get_global_size(0);

for (uint i = get_global_id(0); i < elementsToBeProcessed; i += step)
{
    <process item "i">
}
```

A simplified example: global work size of 5 (artificially small for example), elementsToBeProcessed = 19: first pass through loop elements 0-4 are processed, second pass 5-9, third pass 10-14, forth pass 15-18.

You'd want to tune the fixed global work size to exactly match your hardware (compute units * max work group size or some division of that).

This is not unlike the algorithm for how work items cooperate to copy data into shared local memory regardless of work group size.

Answer (score 0):

Global Work size doesn't have to be fixed. E. g. you have 128 stream processors. So, you make a kernel with local size 128 too. Your global work size can be any number, which is multiple to that value - 256, 4096, etc.

Though, size of local group usually is determined by hardware specs. In case you have more data to process, just increase number of local groups involved.